# GRUB Help and Reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 10 Netbook edition (on my netbook, yes, obvious). My battery died literally, while I was using Ubuntu.

Now, when I restart the computer, it seems that GRUB has duplicated all of the entries in the MBR that pertain to the partition that houses my Ubuntu install. For example:

```
Ubuntu ...
Ubuntu ... (Recovery Mode)
Ubuntu ...
Ubuntu ... (Recovery Mode)
Memtest ...
Memtest ...
Windows (Vista loader)
Windows (Windows 7 starter loader)
```

When I try to access either of the two Ubuntu instances in the boot loader it presents me with an error akin to this:

```
...numbers... Kernel panic ... VFS unable to mount...
```

What I would like to do is:

Wipe out grub, and Ubuntu, and then reinstall Ubuntu (I really only use it for emacs and ess for R so there's nothing in the home directory that I need to backup)

How would I go about "resetting" my system? Or fixing the issue that I have.

Thanks in advance!

BEB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there is some issue with loading the initrd: possibly
the GRUB configuration file is corrupt.  If you want to try fixing
your existing install, I would try the following:

1. Boot from live CD or USB stick (the Ubuntu Wiki has [instructions on how to prepare a bootable installation USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick))
2. Re-install GRUB; some instructions are available in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5250/grub-boot-error-the-second-sector-of-stage-2-is-unknown).

However, if you don't have any valuable data on the disk, it may just
be simpler to reinstall: just use the Ubuntu Live CD or a [bootable
USB key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick),
wipe out your existing Linux partitions (using the "Manual
partitioning scheme" in the installation; you can also let the installer
"Use whole disk for Ubuntu" if you don't have Windows or other OSes on
the disk), and then proceeed installing as usual.

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo, I ended up rebooting from USB, deleting the partitions for the Ubuntu install, rebooting and reinstalling.

Comment: Riccardo, it's a dual boot system, if I let it use the whole disk - wouldn't it remove the Windows install?

Comment: @Brandon Yes, if you let it use the whole disk on a dual-boot system, it will also erase your Windows partitions.  With the manual partition scheme you can select which partitions you want to use for Ubuntu (and mark them for re-formatting).

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to remove the recommendation to "Use whole disk for Ubuntu", I'm just thinking of the passerby who uses this part of the solution when they may not have intended to.

Comment: @Brandon I've reworded the sentence, adding a caveat.  Do you think it suffices?

Comment: Sure does, just wouldn't want a passerby to wipe out their windows install! Some of us still need it! :)